# Double complex integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, reference-request, contour-integration

So basically I want to integrate over two complex variables, so my integration will look something like this

$\int uv\cdot e^{-uv}dudv$

where u and v are complex coordinates, in this case two dimensional (u=x+iy) and v=(x-iy). Im wondering how to solve this integral. I have seen a number of different suggestions. Can someone point me in the right direction or in the direction of some appropriate literature?

Comment: Is this meant to be an indefinite integral, or a definite integral?

Comment: Actually sorry it will be a definite integral as it is acting over some contour

Comment: Some contour in $\Bbb C \times \Bbb C$?

Comment: yes so essentially its an integration over two complex planes.. I wondered initially if we could transform to a line integral and solve that way however i have only even seen this done with a single complex function

Comment: It is important not to conflate the notion of a *real* line integral in $\Bbb R^2$ (which is useful in understand integration in $\Bbb C$) to the notion of a *complex* line integral in $\Bbb C^2$ (which seems like it would be related to, but not quite the same, as a line integral in $\Bbb R^4$).

Comment: Note that the formula for a line integral in $\Bbb R^2$ is something like
$$
\int_{P} f\, d \ell = \int_a^b f(\vec c(t))\,\|\vec c'(t)\|\,dt
$$
Where $\vec c$ is an $\Bbb R^2$ valued parameterization of our path, $P$, over $[a,b] \subset \Bbb R$.
We would like, then, something like
$$
\int_{\Gamma} f\, d \ell = \int_{\gamma} f(\vec \kappa (t))\,\|\vec \kappa'(t)\|\,dt
$$
Where $\kappa:\Bbb C \to \Bbb C^2$ is a parameterization of our path $\Gamma$ over some contour $\gamma \subset \Bbb C$.  It is not clear, however, what exactly $\|\kappa\|$ should be defined when $\kappa$ is a complex vector.

Comment: For example, it is not clear whether $\|\kappa\|$ should be real-valued in this context.

Comment: One interpretation that may yield useful results, however, is to use the norm over $\Bbb C^2$ induced by the sesquilinear inner product, which is to say that $\|(w,z)\|^2 = |w|^2 + |z|^2$.  However, perhaps it would be better if $\|(w,z)\|^2$ were complex-differentiable.

Comment: Ok thanks. I appreciate the time you have taken to answer. Is there any literature/articles or anything that you can recommend that may help me and provide some insight?

Answer (score 0):

It is rare that one encounters an *indefinite* integral over two variables, and I myself have never seen such an idea defined explicitly.  However, the notions of differentiation and indefinite/definite integration over a single *complex* variable certainly exist, and are considered a part of what is broadly referred to as *complex analysis*.

As for your question, perhaps we can simply interpret your integral as
$$
\int\left[\int uv\,e^{-uv}\,du \right]dv
$$
In other words, we would be solving the *partial differential equation*
$$
\frac{\partial^2 f(u,v)}{\partial u \,\partial v} = uv e^{-uv}
$$